# Adding dashes inbetween lines

Tags: python

So I have a code that I would like to print out like this:

```
----------
Tom Cruise
Los Angeles, CA
http://www.tomcruise.com
Official TomCruise.com crew tweets. We love you guys! 
Visit us at Facebook!
['katieH', 'NicoleKidman']
----------
Perez Hilton
Hollywood, California
http://www.PerezH...
Perez Hilton is the creator and writer of one of the most famous websites
in the world. And he also loves music - a lot!
['tomCruise', 'katieH', 'NicoleKidman']
----------
```

However, I don't know how to add dashes so that it will look like that. If I do something like

```
dashes = '----------\n'
result = "\n".join((str(v) for v in lst))
combined = dashes + result
print(result)
```

It will look something like:

```
----------
Tom Cruise
Los Angeles, CA
http://www.tomcruise.com
Official TomCruise.com crew tweets. We love you guys! 
Visit us at Facebook!
['katieH', 'NicoleKidman']
----------
Perez Hilton
Hollywood, California
http://www.PerezH...
Perez Hilton is the creator and writer of one of the most famous   websites
in the world. And he also loves music - a lot!
['tomCruise', 'katieH', 'NicoleKidman']
```

However, I need to add one more line of dashes at the end and if I do print(result + dashes), it comes out funky. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you simply missing a `\n` before the second `dashes`?

```
print(dashes + result + '\n' + dashes)
```

Although I must say this seems a strange way to do things; why not just print each thing separately? No need for newline characters at all.

```
dashes = '----------'
print(dashes)
for line in lst:
    print(line)
print(dashes)
```

Comment: Because although I'm printing it, its only for me to double check that I got a function down right. I was thinking I could add the first part together? ie. combined = dashes + result and then print(combined + result)